# Only 1 core per executor in Spark Yarn mode, despite --num-executors setting

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, emr

I'm running Spark on EMR. I submit my step on EMR with the following:

`spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --num-executors 15 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 3G`

Despite this, my Resource Manager UI shows that each of the 3 nodes has 4 or 6 YARN containers, each with 1 core, and 3G of memory.

The nodes each have 16 cores and 30G of RAM.

It seems that YARN creates as many 1-core/3GB containers as it can, until it runs out of memory on the node. This leaves 10+ cores unused.

Why is Spark not honouring my `--executor-cores` setting?